# Deleting Item Group SAP B1

Tags: hana, sapb1

#### Description

I am after reducing my company's total item groups from 50 to 20 or so.

I am now trying to remove the item groups that have no items in them.

#### Problem

I am running into the below error:

**'You cannot remove item groups: First remove item groups from advanced G/L account determination rules'**

#### Attempted Solution

[image]

When I untick active in the Advanced GL Determination Rules I run into the same error.

Does anyone know what I have to remove to allow me to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove that line by right clicking and "Delete Row", keep in mind to remove it from all periods.

Comment: This did not solve the issue.

Comment: You could'nt delete rows or after deleting same error occured when deleting Item group?

Comment: Also consider SQL Server Profiler to see what queries are executed and maybe you'll know what is blocking this transaction.

Comment: When I delete the item groups row from every time period and try to delete I get the same error.